# Case statement in where clause, what's wrong with my query?

Tags: sql, case, presto

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM    
    TABLE.NAME
WHERE 
    TICKET_GROUP IN 
        CASE WHEN ticket_created_at <= CAST('2022-04-01' AS DATE) 
                 THEN  (1500003613882, 360013692813, 114095263234) 
                 ELSE (1500001610322, 360005931333, 1260811380530) 
        END
```

I get this error

> line 8:20: mismatched input 'IN'. Expecting: 'AND', 'EXCEPT', 'FETCH', 'GROUP', 'HAVING', 'INTERSECT', 'LIMIT', 'OFFSET', 'OR', 'ORDER', 'UNION', <EOF>

I tried changing it to '=' instead of IN but it didn't worked.

Comment: The result of a CASE expression is always a _value_, never another expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to "dynamically" define the `IN` values then you can move `TICKET_GROUP IN` inside the `case` statement's result expressions:

```sql
WHERE 
    CASE 
       WHEN ticket_created_at <= CAST('2022-04-01' AS DATE) 
          THEN TICKET_GROUP IN (1500003613882, 360013692813, 114095263234) 
       ELSE TICKET_GROUP IN (1500001610322, 360005931333, 1260811380530) 
    END
```

Or just use the boolean logic with `OR` and `AND`:

```sql
WHERE 
    (ticket_created_at <= CAST('2022-04-01' AS DATE) AND TICKET_GROUP IN (1500003613882, 360013692813, 114095263234))
    OR (TICKET_GROUP IN (1500001610322, 360005931333, 1260811380530))
```

Answer (score 1):

A `CASE` expression **always** produces a *value*, never another expression. Therefore you must structure the `WHERE` clause more like this:

```
WHERE 
   ( ticket_created_at <= CAST('2022-04-01' AS DATE) 
     AND TICKET_GROUP IN (1500003613882, 360013692813, 114095263234) 
   )
   OR (
     ticket_created_at > CAST('2022-04-01' AS DATE)
     AND TICKET_GROUP IN (1500001610322, 360005931333, 1260811380530) 
   )
```

Additionally, we can use [`NULLIF()`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html#nullif) to simplify the `CASE` expression in the `SELECT` clause like so:

```
SELECT 
    *,
    COALESCE(NULLIF(C_220_COUNTRY_CODE, 'N/A'), COUNTRY_SALES_POD) AS FINAL_COUNTRY_CODE

FROM    
    CUSTOMER_OPS_HISTORICAL.ZENDESK_HISTORICAL_TICKET_CONSOLIDATED_CUSTOMER_OPS_DASHBOARD
WHERE 
   ( ticket_created_at <= CAST('2022-04-01' AS DATE) 
     AND TICKET_GROUP IN (1500003613882, 360013692813, 114095263234) 
   )
   OR (
     ticket_created_at > CAST('2022-04-01' AS DATE)
     AND TICKET_GROUP IN (1500001610322, 360005931333, 1260811380530) 
   )
```